# Different Style for Select in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: html, css, select, right-to-left

I created an `html` code with `select`, `div` and `td`. `select` tags are inside `div` and `div` is inside `td` tag. When I click on the drop box, I see different `select` style.
I found out that it was from `direction:rtl` in the `css` of `select`.if I set `direction:ltr` , this strange behavior will be gone and Opera would be same as Firefox.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cPJHS.png

you can find this issue on various Persian websites like this, just look at select on Digikala website :

[Digikala](http://www.digikala.com/Search/Category-Mouse/#/Category-Electronic-Devices/Category-Computer-Parts/Category-Mouse/Status-2/SortBy-7/SortCondition-0/Category-Mouse#Category-Electronic-DevicesCategory-Computer-PartsCategory-MouseStatus-2SortBy-7SortCondition-0/)

I have no problem With IE but I want the `select` style in Opera shows the same on Firefox. Does Opera/chrome support `direction:rtl` for `select tag`? Any Idea why are they different?

Comment: Seems like Opera has an issue with support right-to-left `rtl` for `select` droplist.

Comment: what is the version of opera you are using?

Comment: Lastest version.I tested on Chrome,Torch.they are fine.this happens only on opera and i will report to Opera forum.
Opera 29.0.1795.60 , Windows 8.1 64-bit (WoW64)

Comment: 7 years later seems like the problem still exist @behrouz did you get an answer from Opera?